# usage of 'and other similar'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference

I'm correcting someone's article and this one expression really annoys me.

Can **'and other similar'** be used with people? as in

> Web developers, marketers and other similar specialists.

I don't know why but it sounds odd to me while in a sentence like 'and other similar items' the words 'other' and 'similar' seem to be fine...

Cambridge Dictionary says that

> **similar** means looking or being almost, but not exactly, the same

but I can't find any example there in which 'similar' would sit right next to a noun like people etc.

Is it the word *similar* that is off? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example is OK, but it really compares occupations, not people. So I think "Web developers, marketers and other similar occupations/specialties." would be better.

Answer (score 2):

As your dictionary search indicated, there's nothing about 'similar' that makes it not apply to people.  You don't necessarily need the word 'other'.

> We welcome beer-lovers, wine enthusiasts, cheese mavens, and similar devotees of fine foods and beverages.
>
> UK Tories, German CDU members, and similar politicians from eastern Europe met for a round-table discussion.